# How to insert facebook public page feeds in database

Tags: php, mysql, json

How can we insert json response of https://graph.facebook.com/anypage/feed in mysql table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use json_decode

```
json_decode($json,true);
```

And you'll get the results as a multidimentional array.

Use a foreach loop and put everything you need in the db - the date for every item is fundamental.

At regular intervals, check the feed again: if the last element's date is different from the one of what you have in the db, put the new elements in the database as well.